# Image/Video deblurring

Tags: algorithms, computer-vision, image-processing

I am currently working on an algorithm that will help to improve shaken blurry images. I know there are plenty of them, such as deconvolution, that is pretty useful though I don't really know how to "cook" such things.

My current objective is to restore the shaken trajectory and then do some kind of deblurring. (blind deconvolution)

What algorithms considered the best in this area? What standard implementations exist?